# Why some glyphs are missing from dvipdfmx output, in contradiction with pdftex?

Tags: fonts, dvipdfmx

Let's get table for font `cmctt10` .

1) By using `tex` + `dvipdfmx`:

```
$ tex testfont
This is TeX, Version 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2015/Debian) (preloaded format=tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/plain/knuth-lib/testfont.tex

Name of the font to test = cmctt10
Now type a test command (\help for help):)
*\table

*\bye
[1]
Output written on testfont.dvi (1 page, 4424 bytes).
Transcript written on testfont.log.
```

```
$ dvipdfmx testfont.dvi 
testfont.dvi -> testfont.pdf
[1]
dvipdfmx:warning: Glyph "(null)" missing in font "cmctt10".
dvipdfmx:warning: Glyph "(null)" missing in font "cmctt10".
dvipdfmx:warning: Glyph "(null)" missing in font "cmctt10".
dvipdfmx:warning: Glyph "(null)" missing in font "cmctt10".

16039 bytes written
```

2) By using `pdftex`:

```sh
$ pdftex testfont
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015/Debian) (preloaded format=pdftex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/plain/knuth-lib/testfont.tex

Name of the font to test = cmctt10
Now type a test command (\help for help):)
*\table

*\bye
[1{/usr/local/share/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]</usr/share/texli
ve/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/cmcyr/cmctt10.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-di
st/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/font
s/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr7.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/
public/amsfonts/cm/cmti10.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public
/amsfonts/cm/cmtt10.pfb>
Output written on testfont.pdf (1 page, 59482 bytes).
Transcript written on testfont.log.
```

If we do via `dvipdfmx`, slots '31,'35,'36,'177 are empty.

What is wrong with the `dvipdfmx` case?

Comment: Addition: If you use ghostscript, i.e. `dvips`, the glyphs are also all there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

dvipdfmx may not be so clever to understand automatically such a complicated
type1 font. Please create a file with the name `cmctt10.enc`:

```
/CMCTT10Encoding [
/.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef
/.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef
/.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /afii61352
/.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /guillemotleft /guillemotright /.notdef /space
/.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef
/.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef
/.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef
/afii10071 /.notdef /afii10023 /.notdef /afii10096 /afii10065 /afii10066 /afii10088
/afii10069 /afii10070 /afii10086 /afii10068 /afii10087 /afii10074 /afii10075
/afii10076 /afii10077 /afii10078 /afii10079 /afii10080 /afii10081 /afii10097
/afii10082 /afii10083 /afii10084 /afii10085 /afii10072 /afii10067 /afii10094
/afii10093 /afii10073 /afii10090 /afii10095 /afii10091 /afii10089 /afii10092
/afii10048 /afii10017 /afii10018 /afii10040 /afii10021 /afii10022 /afii10038
/afii10020 /afii10039 /afii10026 /afii10027 /afii10028 /afii10029 /afii10030
/afii10031 /afii10032 /afii10033 /afii10049 /afii10034 /afii10035 /afii10036
/afii10037 /afii10024 /afii10019 /afii10046 /afii10045 /afii10025 /afii10042
/afii10047 /afii10043 /afii10041 /afii10044 /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef
/.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef
/.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef
/.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef
/.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef
/.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef
/.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef
/.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef
/.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef
/.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef
/.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef
/.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef
/.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef
/.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef
/.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef
/.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef
/.notdef /.notdef /.notdef /.notdef
] def
```

and a file with the name `cmctt10.map`:

```
cmctt10 cmctt10 <cmctt10.pfb <cmctt10.enc
```

Then

```
dvipdfmx -f cmctt10.map testfont.dvi
```

creates the desired pdf. Note that dvipdfmx knows encoding by `cmctt10.enc`.

Comment: What encoding is used by default if we do not set it in map file? How did you obtain this `cmctt10.enc`?

Comment: default map for `cmctt10` is `cmctt10 cmctt10 <cmctt10.pfb` What does it mean? Why you changed it to `cmctt10 cmctt10 <cmctt10.pfb <cmctt10.enc`? Please give some background information about the syntax of .map file in general. For example, what this means: `mytt10 LMMono10-Regular "encmytt ReEncodeFont" <mytt.enc <mytt10.pfb`? encmytt is the name of the encoding array? Can the same name be used for different fonts with the same encoding (mytt8,mytt9,...) in .map file? I noticed that the name of the vector in .map file does not have to be the same as in .enc file - it works with any name. Why?

Comment: Don't change the default map file. dvipdfmx does not interpret
`dup dup 161 10 getinterval 0 exch putinterval`
`dup dup 173 23 getinterval 10 exch putinterval`
`dup dup 127 exch 196 get put`
`readonly def`
so, I wrote a final enc file for dvipdfmx only.
dvips interprets the above lines, thus if we change cmcyr.map,
dvips may not work.

Comment: I don't understand .enc, .map and .pfb files. Can you recommend a good explanation of these?

Comment: S. Hirata, the author of dvipdfmx, updated it to support downloading
such type1 fonts as cmctt10.pfb. The updated dvipdfmx will be in the
upcoming TeX Live 2016.

Comment: I will test it with all *cmcyr* fonts and report as soon as new dvipdfmx will be packaged in Debian testing. But I want to understand .enc, .map and .pfb files anyway. Do you know a good book or article which explains this topic? What resources did your read yourself to understand this? Please recommend some links for further reading.

Comment: I have confirmed that
`pdftex` and `tex + new dvipdfmx` give the same results for
`cmcb10`
`cmcbx10`
`cmcbxsl10`
`cmcbxti10`
`cmccsc10`
`cmcinch`
`cmcitt10`
`cmcsl10`
`cmcsltt10`
`cmcss10`
`cmcssbx10`
`cmcssdc10`
`cmcssi10`
`cmcssq8`
`cmcssqi8`
`cmcti10`
`cmctt10`
`cmcu10`
`cmcyr10`.

Answer (score 3):

The font `cmctt10.pfb` contains the following part

```
dup dup 161 10 getinterval 0 exch putinterval
dup dup 173 23 getinterval 10 exch putinterval
dup dup 127 exch 196 get put
readonly def
```

for definition of encoding vector.

Dvipdfmx doesn't take into account such cases while pdftex and dvips treat it.
You may use your own `.enc` file to solve this issue.